# Angular Universal : Switching from server side view to client view

Tags: angular, server, rendering, universal, server-side-rendering

I have an Angular 4 project (I'm also using webpack) and I've decided to use angular universal to make Server Side Rendering.

I'm using node (v6.10.2) with express to do the Server Side Rendering. I'm using universal implemented in angular core.

I've used this [example](https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo) as a starting project.

Everything is working fine (I can access the page, the html is correctly rendered, etc) except that there is no switch between the server rendered view and the client view.

Does anyone have a simple solution to this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please go through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited my message to be more specific

Comment: Have you found the solution of switching from server-side rendering to client-side rendering?

Comment: Have the same issue. Would love to hear if you've solved it.